# Ajax Submit using PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

There are may button son php page. I want to submit value of button and the delete record from table using that value. Ajaxz code is

```
$('#product-table td #delete').live("click", function () {
                var doDelete = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
                deleteLinkObj = $(this);

                if (doDelete) {


                    var id = $(this).attr('accesskey');
        $("#deleteid").val(id); 
        $.ajax({
                    url: "purchase.php",
                    data: {deleteid:id},
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function() {

                    }
                });


                }
                else { return false; }
                });
```

On PHP I am trying to use value of deleteid but  its not coming
PHP code is

```
if(@$_POST['deleteid']!="")
                    {
                    $sql="delete from purchasedetails where purchaseid='".$_POST['deleteid']."'";
                    if(!mysql_query($sql))
                            {
                            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $msg="Data is deleted";
                            }
                    }
```

I have tried usinng isset($_POST['deleteid']) then also its showing error

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. SQL injection is [very easy to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/168868). Consider [switching to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  Also, dude, stop using the `@` operator.  Don't hide errors, *fix* errors.

Comment: ...also, post the error you received....

Comment: There is No error shown by it. It deosn't delete the record after confirming it is to be deleted.'@' is used to hide the warning Message ' variable not initialized'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax call you aren't setting the request method to `POST`, therefore it will default to `GET`, that is why your post var is never present:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "purchase.php",
                data: {deleteid:id},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function() {

                }
            });
```

As a quick fix for your SQL Injection vulnerability you can cast the id as `int`, but you should consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi because the library you're using is deprecated.

```
$sql="delete from purchasedetails where purchaseid='".(int)$_POST['deleteid']."'";
```

Storing your `purchaseid` as the elements accesskey is not the best place, it would be better as a `data-myid` attribute, so you can access it with `$(this).data('myid')`.

Comment: I have tried it using POST but still the problem is same.The value is not getting submitted

Comment: Move the id from the accesskey and verify it's present in the HTML (view->source). Then watch the request in Firebug or Chrome dev tools to see what is sent.

Comment: used data-myid and then done casting of id in delete command it has worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default $.ajax take type as GET, hence you need to define the type in you code

You can try like this [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) syntax-

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "purchase.php",
                data: $("#deleteid").val(id),
                type: POST
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function() {
```

Comment: Tried using POSt but still it doesn't submit the value.